# Android detect string/user input language

Tags: android, android-edittext

can I determine which language the user enter to editText ?

example :

if the user enter "поэзия song" witch contain from english and russian letter the methood return english, russian.

i dont care if the methood detect the language in the keybourd and return english, russian just becuase the user use in english and russian keybourds.

i prefere the second option becuase there is aproblam to determaine the language if it is UK becuase they use in the same letters

UPDATE:

there is away to tranlate variable (string) to user  language  and if editText contain english so no tranlate ?

like this :

```
string = "song" ; 
englishletter = "abc..." ; 

for(int i = 0 ; i < string.length(); i++ ){
  if( string.contains(englishletter.substring(i,i+1)) {
    num++;
  } 
}

if (num==0){   
  system.out.print(string.tranlsate());
} else { 
  system.out.print(string)  ; 
}
```

Comment: Please check your grammar and spelling in the question, so that we can analyze it easier and attempt to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything in Android that will do this for you. I would suggest integrating a library like this one: [language-detection](https://code.google.com/p/language-detection/)